# Measuring Transients in the circuit

Tags: pcb

I am measuring current and voltage transients in the power distribution network. The test case requires a measurement of the current reading at one site (Integrated Chip 1) of the board, which will cause an opening to be measured with a digital multimeter, while measuring the transient spikes at another site (Integrated Chip 2) of the board. Both of these sites share a common power bus line of 3.3 volts. Would it pose a concern? In theory, from what I know, when the trace for the PCB is broken open for current measurement, the leads, interconnects, etc. cause parasitic inductance, which may introduce unwanted noise or spikes. If I am not clear in my question, please kindly correct me. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transients of the speed you're implying and multimeters don't go together. The impedance added in series with the supply has to be small enough not to disturb the circuit - and not kill it, most importantly. A loop through a multimeter current shunt has so much inductance it will not only add voltage transients of its own, but those transients may be large enough to cause spurious resets/faults.

The 3.3V supply is likely a power plane, not a trace, so "breaking" it may be hard.

Usually such measurements are made on instrumented boards. The PCB is designed with the measurement in mind, and has suitably high bandwidth current shunts and coaxial probe connectors built-in.

It really is easiest to get good results, with good signal integrity, when instrumentation is an integral part of the PCB design. The circuitry can be then deleted from the production board.

Adding high-bandwidth current sensing on boards already laid out and not taking this test requirement into account is hard and requires either custom sensor boards with off-the-shelf parts, or high-cost high-bandwidth miniature current sensors. High cost: think $1k apiece or more. Well worth the price if you need them, but well worth avoiding if you can.